# How can I effectively clear part of the Graphics layer in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a rendering engine using Swing.
Now I have run into a very odd problem.

Imagine we must draw something on our Graphics2D context, and then clear it. Should notice here that I'm drawing on a `BufferedImages`'s context, but it shouldn't matter, as `paintComponent()` method later simply outputs that image to the screen.

So I should draw something, then apply some custom blurring code, then repaint my area partly (I'm making a box-shadow). And I need to use the alpha channel so that my layer must be able to be partly transparent.

Now I am using this code for repainting a custom image area:

```
private void repaintRegion(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, int w, int h, BufferedImage img) {

    g2d.clearRect(x, y, w, h);
    composite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OUT, 1f);
    g2d.setComposite(composite);
    g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);

    composite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1f);
    g2d.setComposite(composite);

    g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
}
```

After that it is just fine. But if I remove painting in SRC_OUT mode, I get a black rectangle.

But this way it also works fine:

```
private void repaintRegion(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, int w, int h, BufferedImage img) {

    AlphaComposite composite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR, 1f);
    g2d.setComposite(composite);

    g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

    composite = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1f);
    g2d.setComposite(composite);

    g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
}
```

Can someone explain me, why it is so, and what is happening when I am using clearRect()?

Comment: What's the question? The way you state it, you found two solutions to your stated problem.

Comment: The question is why clearRect() method does clear the area in such a way that it cannot be repainted. And how in fact is it implemented under the hood. I would like to understand things, not just to wander around blindly trying to make some "magic" in order to get the needed result :)

Comment: Okay, so I'm confused, what's the point of call `clearRect`, followed by `drawImage` using `SRC_OUT` in the first example - this is just going to remove the area of the `Graphics` context and the paint the image into using `SCR_OUT` composite ... isn't the point to try and combine what existed with the `img`?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [Compositing Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html) for an example of the various composites

Comment: >this is just going to remove the area of the Graphics context and the paint the image into using SCR_OUT composite - theoretically, yes. But what will be in the real example - I can show on screenshots.

Comment: >isn't the point to try and combine what existed with the img? - No, the point is to completely overwrite what existed. But somehow I get black squares in the corners, even after painting with `SRC_OVER`. I guess this mode multiplies alpha values of cleared pixels and of painted pixels, and multiplication by zero gives zero. Is there a way to avoid it and get the alpha value of the pixels of the image that I am painting with `drawImage()`?

Comment: Ok, still missing something - however - `Graphics#clearRect` will *"Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color of the current drawing surface. This operation does not use the current paint mode."* - Which is likely to use `BLACK` as the default color. `SRC_OUT` will *"If pixels in the source and the destination overlap, only the source pixels outside of the overlapping area are rendered"* - So, you'd end up with a black rectangle.

Comment: Where as `CLEAR` will *"If the pixels in the source and the destination overlap, the pixels in the overlapping area are cleared."* which I believe is setting the alpha state of this pixels

Comment: >"If the pixels in the source and the destination overlap, the pixels in the overlapping area are cleared." which I believe is setting the alpha state of this pixels - thanks for the explanation. Now I see that I needed exactly `CLEAR` mode, and not `Graphics#clearRect` method.

Answer (score 2):

I use `clearRect()` in my applications and it works fine. However, I don't mess with the composite property of the context.

Keep in mind you also might need to make sure the background color is transparent (I believe the default is black) as `clearRect()` uses that as the fill color for what it clears (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Also make sure that the `BufferedImage` you are drawing on has an alpha channel (use an image type with an alpha channel when calling the constructor) see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#field_summary for options.

To be totally proper, you could use the `GraphisEnvironment` to construct the `BufferedImage`:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()
                .createCompatibleImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: I tried tansparent color as paint color in `fillRect` method and as the background color before calling `clearRect`, and it still looked like black. And my `BufferedImage` supports alpha channel, it's certainly true (I can see the graphics "through" it, and the way I constructed it implies alpha support).